# Bootstrap CSS Padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for a blog and am having a padding issue with my div

.navbar .brand

For some reason it has a margin or padding on the top part of that div and I can't figure out what is causing the issue. I have a margin:0; padding: 0; and top:0; and am over-riding the height but this doesn't seem to help.

link: http://www.bryananthonylewis.com/

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove these properties from styles.css:

```
.navbar .brand {
    float: none;
}

div.nav-collapse {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: well, that worked but that is because bootstrap auto puts float: left; which works but I'm wanting to center that title. Is that possible?

Comment: You could add span4, span5, etc. to the anchor tag (to increase the width) and the text would be centered.

Comment: That isn't working the way I had hoped it would. Will continue to mess around.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, where would you like to have your logo? thmled was right, but i prefer this in style.css, line 94:

```
.navbar .brand {
    padding: 10px 20px
    float:left
}
```

Set float right or left, it depending on place, you would like to have your logo.